# ZoomFloppy and Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, hardware, pi-3, linux

I would like to install a [ZoomFloppy](http://www.go4retro.com/products/zoomfloppy/) to my Raspberry Pi 3.
How can I do that?
I just found older instructions for windows and macs.
I'd like to have a step by step guide to do so.
TIA

Comment: This would appear to be a niche product and you may not find anyone here who has even heard of it. Wouldn't it make more sense to ask the product manufacturer?

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange network. I'm a bit rusty on the Commodore series of computers but the linked-to forums did have this post: [Raspberry Pi 3 as C64 how to use real drive?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zoomfloppy-users/4ZZVNV1TGUg) which might give you some pointers.  It also looks like a powered hub might be useful as that unit and any attached drives (although they could, of course, be self-powered) would be supplied from the USB connection. For the record this is all speculation on my part so if an expert wants to chime in...!

Comment: @SlySven I want to use the Pi to act as a storage device. Not as a replacement for the C64 as shown in the link you provided. But thanks maybe I can use some of the hints given.